# How can I use a bootstrap slider in my WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

I want to put a bootstrap slider in my WordPress theme. how can i put featured images, as well as posts in it. I don't really want to use a plugin. Are there any WordPress functions i can use to achieve this? I'm pretty new at WordPress so any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use a query, loop through the results filling in the carousel as you go.     This should be pretty close - probably needs a tweak or two to work with your setup.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'staff' ) );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

  ?>

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">    

        <?php for ($i=1;$i<$the_query->post_count;$i++) { ?>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>" ></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $id = get_the_ID();

        if (has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ), 'full' );
        }
    ?>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title;?>">
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```